# How do I force a page reload on Hooks state change?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using react hooks and need to do a page refresh on state change.

I tried using `window.location.reload()` but this doesn't result in a proper refresh.

```
const responseGoogle = async googleData => {
    await userLogin(googleData);
    setLoggedIn(true);
    window.location.reload()
  };
```

Only a manual F5 refresh does the job!

Is there anything that's like a full refresh in React?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using react-router?

Comment: I'm using react-router-dom

Answer (score 0):

If you mean just to re-render the page you can use hooks function,

```
const [dummy, reload] = useState(false);
```

and when you want to re-render just call the reload function

```
reload(!dummy);
```

just remember to import the useState from react;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are running the `window.location.reload()` even the await promise fails. I would suggest to use `trycatch` in async functions to easily determine if it's successful or not.

You may try this code below

```
const responseGoogle = async googleData => {
  try {
    await userLogin(googleData);
    setLoggedIn(true);
    window.location.reload() //this will run if the await userLogin is succeeded
  } catch (error) { 
   console.log(error); //will show an error if it fails
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually all I had to do was to pass a boolean into the function: `window.location.reload(true)` to force the reload.